# view the json in the response of postman

Tags: python, json, flask

i have a flask application ,this receive the json  and return this json, i would like this return this json this way in postman: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utlhX.png) but i receive the json :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4suWO.png)

this is my code:

```
import requests
import codecs, json
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask('')
api = Api(app)
class Test(Resource):
  def post(selft):
      result = request.get_json() 
      return jsonify(result)
  def get(self):
      return "Example with Flask-Restful"
api.add_resource(Test,'/')
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080',debug=True)
```

Comment: just as an FYI, there is no functional difference between the two results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. Set the the following config value before `app.run()`:
   `app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False`
2. Use `return json.dumps(result)` instead, but you'll lose the stuff that `jsonify` does (such as setting return type headers). This can be fixed though by using the code below:

```py
from flask import make_response
import json


class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json() 
        response = make_response(json.dumps(data)) # json.dumps has indent=0 by default
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        response.headers['mimetype'] = 'application/json'
        return response
```

Please note that there's still a difference between this option and what POSTMAN returns, namely the space after the `:`

Sidenote, give your app a proper name, instead of `app = Flask('')` use `app = Flask(__name__)`